# How can I view my starred items across all Google tools?

Tags: google

I'm a fairly heavy user of Google tools & am wondering if it's possible to view all items starred in each application.

For example, I remember reading about  in something recently and am trying to find the reference.  I don't know if it was in an email, or a Doc/Presentation or a site I starred in Chrome (but I know I starred it!).

Is there a central location I can use to search these things?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The various "stars" that Google uses in its apps are not part of a universal system. Only Gmail knows about the stars in Gmail, only Google Chrome knows about your stars (although if you're syncing your bookmarks, at least *all* of your browsers will know about the stars), only Google Drive knows about your Google Drive stars.

You might want to look into a service like [Pocket](https://getpocket.com) to squirrel away things you want to get back to later, but even that's only a partial solution. (It won't really help you with a Gmail message, for instance.)